# Spark reducebykey - minimum of list element-wise

Tags: list, apache-spark, reduce, minimum

I'm having trouble using Spark reduceByKey / groupByKey functions.

I have a pair RDD of form `(datetime, [a1, b1, c1, d1]), (datetime, [a2, b2, c2, d2]) ...`

I'd like to group those elements by key (same datetime here), and get an output value corresponding to a list of element-wise minimum.

With my example the output would be:

`(datetime, [min(a1,a2), min(b1,b2), min(c1,c2), min(d1,d2)])`

I've tried:

```
reduceByKey(lambda (a, b): [min(x) for x in zip(a, b)])
```

but unsuccessfully so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your attempt looks OK at the first glance. What exactly do you mean by _unsuccessfully_?

Comment: I was returned a `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` error when trying the above. Just removed the parentheses of the lambda object (a,b) and seems like it's working.. but I can't seem to understand why... Thanks anyway !

Comment: Oh, I missed parentheses. Use `lambda a, b: [min(x) for x in zip(a, b)]`

Answer (score -1):

Well for this issue we have a easy solution.

In your map function, before the reduce. You should set your data like this:

```
(datetime, ([a1, b1, c1, d1],))
```

Note, that I insert the list inside a tuple with a comma. This I'm doing a "open" tuple. And as it you can do your `reduceByKey` as default:

```
reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

and you will get the rdd like this:

```
(datetime, ([a1, b1, c1, d1], [a2, b2, c2, d2]))
```

Comment: This really doesn't address the problem. OP want element wise minimum not grouping. And the whole problem seems to be params definition.